# Laravel Many to Many with polymorphic relation on both ends

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, many-to-many

I have 4 models:

- `RegulatedAgreement` and `LeasingAgreement` that are agreements,
- `Associate` and `Executive` that are contractors.

Here is my pivot table :

```
Schema::create('agreement_contractor', static function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->nullableMorphs('agreement');
  $table->nullableMorphs('contractor');
});
```

When I call for exemple : `$regulatedAgreement->contractors` I want to retrieve all contractors, `Associate` and `Executive`.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

I tried to create a custom pivot model that extends `Model` or `Pivot` or event `MorphPivot` but I can't get my head around this and I am not quite sure which relation to use.

Comment: I am not sure what issue you have, please state it. What did you try that did not work? `agreement_contractor` should be a `MorphPivot` because you are storing `agreement_id` and `agreement_type`, and `contractor_id` and `contractor_type`, so create a model class extending `MorphPivot` and define both relationships there (if you want to use those). Another question, why are you using `static function` instead of `function`?

Comment: My issue is that i don't know which relations to use at all.
I created AgreementContractor extending MorphPivot but i don't know which relation i am supposed to put inside. I am missing something.
I tried morphedByMany, morphToMany, morphTo..
static or not does not matter here, phpstorm was screaming at me, that's all.